# Json4s unable to desrialize in scala

Tags: scala, json4s

I need a help in json desrialization in scala using Json4s. I get the following error when I try to desrialize the json

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 cannot be cast to 
 LocationServiceTest$$anonfun$1$LocationList$3
 java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 cannot be cast to 
 LocationServiceTest$$anonfun$1$LocationList$3
at LocationServiceTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(LocationServiceTest.scala:34)
at LocationServiceTest$$anonfun$1.apply(LocationServiceTest.scala:16)
at LocationServiceTest$$anonfun$1.apply(LocationServiceTest.scala:16)
```

My Json as follows :

```
    {
  "locations" : [
    {
      "country": "YY",
      "placeName": "YY",
      "latitude": "YY",
      "longitude": "YY"
    },
    {
      "country": "XX",
      "placeName": "XX",
      "latitude": "XX",
      "longitude": "XX"
    },
```

My code :

```
case class Location(country: String, placeName: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
 val locations = parse(scala.io.Source.fromFile("input.json").mkString)
  println(locations.values.asInstanceOf[LocationList])
```

Using extract(format, manifest) also fails.. Can someone please help.

Comment: is it necessary for you to use json4s?

Comment: Could you share `LocationList` code, please? i guess that it is something like `LocationList(locations:  Seq[Location])` but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: `extract` is the function you should use. Please, show how you use it and what is the error you get.

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is shown below:

```
object Test extends App {
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
  implicit val formats =DefaultFormats

  val str = scala.io.Source.fromFile("input.json").mkString

  case class Location(country: String, placeName: String, latitude: String, longitude: String)

  val dataObj= parse(str)
  val locObj = (dataObj \ "locations").extract[Seq[Location]]

  println(locObj)
}
```

The output:

```
List(Location(YY,YY,YY,YY), Location(XX,XX,XX,XX))
```

Note that in case class, latitude and longitude are string since in json, you declared them as string.

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

The `parse` function creates `JValue` (JSON representation in Scala types, like `Map`, `Array` and primitive types). That type is not in any way related to some custom type, like `LocationList`. For that you need to use `json.extract`. See [https://github.com/json4s/json4s Extracting values](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extracting-values):

> Case classes can be used to extract values from parsed JSON
>
> `json.extract[Person]`